# Apache2 -Indexes causes server to fail

Tags: apache, apache2, directory-listing

I want to prevent Directory listing, in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I have this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And I add the `-` before `Indexes`. When I restart the server I get an error in that line.

I have this version: `Apache/2.4.10` and I have done this before for preventing directory listing without problems, but I don't know why is this happening now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options

> **Note**
>
> Mixing `Options` with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax and will be rejected during server startup by the syntax check
>   with an abort.

So instead of:

```
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

You should use:

```
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
```